# Problems with curve_fit() for parabola

Tags: python, csv, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm having trouble applying a curve_fit() to data from a .csv file. The .csv file is real data taken from a basketball bouncing multiple times underneath a motion sensor. The plot of the data points is ball height vs time, and the resulting graph shows a series of diminishing parabolas. Making that plot is a piece of cake, but I obviously have no idea what I'm doing with curve_fit(). I think the issue is with my choice of coefficients a, b, and c, though I thought b and c would begin at 0, and a, as stated in the homework assignment, is supposed to be g/2, where g is of course -9.81. Unfortunately, the curve_fit only shows a large downward parabola that bears no relation to the data. Where am I going wrong? I also can't figure out how to include a csv file with this question, so I have pasted the data below the code. I entered it as part of the code to maintain the format. If there is a way to include a data file in these questions, please enlighten me.

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit  

dname=r'my_computer_directory'  **#replace with your own directory name**                    
fname='free_fall_run18_csv.csv'                                
dfname ='{0:s}/{1:s}'.format(dname,fname)                  

data01=np.genfromtxt(dfname,delimiter=',',skip_header=1)   # data01 is a ndarray
                                                           # skip one header -> skip_header=1
                                                           # csv             -> delimiter=','
count = 0
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        count +=1
        n1 = count-1
print ('Number of data points is', count-1) 

t = data01[:,0]       
y = data01[:,1]*(-1)      

# remove any negative times
t_temp=t[np.where(t>0)]
y_temp=y[np.where(t>0)]

def myline1(t,a,b,c):
    y=a*t**2+b*t+c
    return y

g=-9.81
a0=g/2
b0=0
c0=0
popt0,pcov0 = curve_fit(myline1,t_temp,y_temp,p0=[a0,b0,c0])
a0=popt0[0]   
b0=popt0[1]
c0=popt0[2]
y_hat1=a0*t_temp**2+b0*t_temp+c0 

#fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t_temp,y_temp, '.', label = 'Height vs Time')
plt.grid() #show grid
plt.title('Height vs Time')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time [s]') #label axis
plt.ylabel('Height [m]') #label axis
plt.show() #show figure

plt.plot(t_temp,y_temp, '.', label = 'Height vs Time') 
plt.plot(t_temp,y_hat1, '-', label = 'Height vs Time with curve_fit()')
plt.grid() #show grid
plt.title('Height vs Time with curve_fit()')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time [s]') #label axis
plt.ylabel('Height [m]') #label axis
plt.show() #show figure

#.csv data   
Time (s),Position (m)
0,0.152
0.025,0.152
0.05,0.152
0.075,0.152
0.1,0.151
0.125,0.151
0.15,0.151
0.175,0.151
0.2,0.15
0.225,0.15
0.25,0.151
0.275,0.151
0.3,0.151
0.325,0.15
0.35,0.15
0.375,0.149
0.4,0.148
0.425,0.147
0.45,0.146
0.475,0.145
0.5,0.144
0.525,0.143
0.55,0.143
0.575,0.143
0.6,0.144
0.625,0.144
0.65,0.145
0.675,0.146
0.7,0.147
0.725,0.148
0.75,0.154
0.775,0.166
0.8,0.184
0.825,0.207
0.85,0.238
0.875,0.273
0.9,0.316
0.925,0.364
0.95,0.417
0.975,0.477
1,0.543
1.025,0.615
1.05,0.694
1.075,0.78
1.1,0.869
1.125,0.964
1.15,1.066
1.175,1.19
1.2,1.105
1.225,1.019
1.25,0.94
1.275,0.867
1.3,0.802
1.325,0.741
1.35,0.687
1.375,0.639
1.4,0.596
1.425,0.56
1.45,0.53
1.475,0.505
1.5,0.488
1.525,0.475
1.55,0.469
1.575,0.468
1.6,0.474
1.625,0.485
1.65,0.502
1.675,0.525
1.7,0.554
1.725,0.589
1.75,0.63
1.775,0.677
1.8,0.73
1.825,0.791
1.85,0.853
1.875,0.924
1.9,1.003
1.925,1.087
1.95,1.19
1.975,1.119
2,1.045
2.025,0.98
2.05,0.921
2.075,0.867
2.1,0.822
2.125,0.781
2.15,0.747
2.175,0.718
2.2,0.696
2.225,0.679
2.25,0.668
2.275,0.663
2.3,0.663
2.325,0.669
2.35,0.682
2.375,0.7
2.4,0.725
2.425,0.755
2.45,0.792
2.475,0.834
2.5,0.882
2.525,0.937
2.55,0.997
2.575,1.064
2.6,1.147
2.625,1.153
2.65,1.092
2.675,1.036
2.7,0.987
2.725,0.945
2.75,0.907
2.775,0.876
2.8,0.851
2.825,0.831
2.85,0.82
2.875,0.813
2.9,0.812
2.925,0.816
2.95,0.826
2.975,0.843
3,0.865
3.025,0.894
3.05,0.929
3.075,0.969
3.1,1.016
3.125,1.068
3.15,1.132
3.175,1.166
3.2,1.113
3.225,1.066
3.25,1.026
3.275,0.991
3.3,0.963
3.325,0.94
3.35,0.923
3.375,0.913
3.4,0.908
3.425,0.91
3.45,0.917
3.475,0.93
3.5,0.95
3.525,0.975
3.55,1.006
3.575,1.043
3.6,1.086
3.625,1.141
3.65,1.161
3.675,1.117
3.7,1.078
3.725,1.045
3.75,1.019
3.775,0.998
3.8,0.984
3.825,0.975
3.85,0.972
3.875,0.975
3.9,0.985
3.925,1
3.95,1.022
3.975,1.049
4,1.083
4.025,1.123
4.05,1.174
4.075,1.136
4.1,1.102
4.125,1.074
4.15,1.051
4.175,1.035
4.2,1.025
4.225,1.021
4.25,1.023
4.275,1.03
4.3,1.044
4.325,1.063
4.35,1.089
4.375,1.121
4.4,1.167
4.425,1.148
4.45,1.117
4.475,1.093
4.5,1.075
4.525,1.063
4.55,1.057
4.575,1.056
4.6,1.062
4.625,1.074
4.65,1.091
4.675,1.115
4.7,1.149
4.725,1.161
4.75,1.133
4.775,1.112
4.8,1.096
4.825,1.086
4.85,1.082
4.875,1.084
4.9,1.092
4.925,1.107
4.95,1.127
4.975,1.158
5,1.16
5.025,1.137
5.05,1.121
5.075,1.11
5.1,1.105
```

Comment: Typo: `A0=popt0[0]` should be `a0=popt0[0]`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. The curve_fit still doesn't work though.

Comment: Your data consists of multiple bounces, while your function describes a single downward trajectory.  The curve fitting routine will dutifully force the curve through the data points as best it can, regardless of whether it's the right formula to describe the physics of the situation.  It's just math, not magic - it doesn't know what the data points represent.  You either need a different equation (describing a bouncing object) or you need to pick out the parts of the data that the equation actually models.